# How to be able to determine whether my microphone will work when in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: ms-word, microsoft-teams

When I tried to turn on video once it simply displayed black screen on Teams and I am afraid that this time my microphone won't work as well. Is there a way to determine whether my microphone will work before the meeting starts?

[UPDATE]

So, in my privacy settings I enabled MsTeams to access my microphone should, is it necessary to restart the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on your name in the top right of the Teams client, and go to Settings, there's an option inside there to test your hardware by making a Test call (it's under the "Devices" section in the left menu), similar to what classic "Skype" used to do.